# Tengo errores al momento de ejecutar mi app en Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Flutter 3.10.5 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 796c8ef792 (4 weeks ago) • 2023-06-13 15:51:02 -0700
Engine • revision 45f6e00911
Tools • Dart 3.0.5 • DevTools 2.23.1

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No tengo errores en el código, mas me saltan los problemas en la imagen

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: El código y los mensajes de error siempre _como texto, con formato_. Además, debes mostrar un [repro] del código en cuestión. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: ¿Has probado a hacer flutter clean y luego flutter pub get?